# Способ уменьшения ошибок в программе

Tags: c, typedef

В процессе изучения появилась такая мысль использования typedef:

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef int height;
typedef int width;
typedef int mul;

mul sq(height,width);

int main(){
        width h=5;/*or 'int' or other type*/
        width w=17;
        printf("%d\n",sq(h,w));
}
mul sq(height h,width w){
        return h * w;
}
```

но фишка не удалась. И я, как и следовало ожидать, получил не то что хотел.Я понял, что у меня в примере функция аналогична такой:

```
    int sq(int h,int w){
        return h * w;
}
```

А хотелось бы, чтобы при принятии в функцию не соответствующего типа выходила ошибка или предупреждение компилятора. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Можно в структуру обернуть.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, чего хотелось бы.

Comment: В языке Go такой подход уже реализован.

Comment: Если собираете [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)  то можно использовать `__builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(...))` в формате макроса.

Comment: typedef не определяет новый тип, а всего лишь вводит синоним. Если хотите определить полноценный тип, то вам дорога в C++.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В языке С создание пользовательских типов, способных нести произвольные данные, возможно только через определение новых struct-типов, array-типов или enum-типов. Enum-типы в С всегда целочисленны и свободно конвертируемы между собой, что делает их непригодными для решения данной задачи. Array-типы подходят плохо, имеют свойство деградировать до указателей и являются некопируемыми, что делает их непригодными для решения данной задачи тоже.

Остаются только struct-типы. Придется заворачивать значения в struct-типы с одним полем. Это, однако, сделает код довольно перегруженным повторяющимися синтаксическими деталями. Составные литералы и, возможно, `_Generic` помогут сделать код более элегантным, но превратить С в С++ все равно не смогут. Так что вопрос в том, насколько сильно вам этого хочется.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { int value; } height;
typedef struct { int value; } width;
typedef struct { int value; } area;

area sq(height h, width w)
{
  return (area) { h.value * w.value };
}

int main()
{
  width h = { 5 };
  width w = { 17 };
  height h2 = { 5 };
  // printf("%d\n", sq(h, w).value);
  printf("%d\n", sq(h2, w).value);
}
```

Comment: Зато `enum`'ом можно задать максимальный размер, в пределах `sizeof(int)` конечно.